# Azure Service Bus SendMessageAsync method terminates and crashes whole program

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I created a .NET core 6 project. I added `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` as the dependency. I am using below code to send message to service bus topic.

```
   // See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

Sender t = new Sender();
Sender.Send();

class Sender
{
  
public static async Task Send()
{
    string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://sb-test-one.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=manage;SharedAccessKey=8e+6SWp3skB3AeDlwH6ufGEainEs45353435JzDywz5DU=;";
    string topicName = "topicone";
    string subscriptionName = "subone";

    // The Service Bus client types are safe to cache and use as a singleton for the lifetime
    try
    {

        await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString, new ServiceBusClientOptions
        {
            TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
        });

        // create the sender
        ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(topicName);
        dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
        data.name = "Abc";
        data.age = 6;

        // create a message that we can send. UTF-8 encoding is used when providing a string.
        
        var messageBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
        
        ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(messageBody);
        // send the message
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);

       
        var s = 10;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var v = 10;
    }

    //// create a receiver for our subscription that we can use to receive the message
    //ServiceBusReceiver receiver = client.CreateReceiver(topicName, subscriptionName);

    //// the received message is a different type as it contains some service set properties
    //ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage = await receiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();

    //// get the message body as a string
    //string body = receivedMessage.Body.ToString();
    //Console.WriteLine(body);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end the application");
    Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Issue:**  When I call `await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);` after this line get executed, the **program is actually terminating**. It not `awating`. The whole execution stops after this line.

**System is not throwing any exception and service bus is not receiving any message.**

I just noticed that all other samples I saw had a default **SharedAccessPolicy** called **RootManageSharedAccessKey** policy available by default in the azure portal. For me, I had to create this policy. To my policy I have given Manage, Send, ReceiveAccess.

Comment: Is there a blocking call (e.g., `.Wait()`, `.Result`, or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`) further up in your call stack?

Comment: @StephenCleary: Nope. I shared the entire code.  I copied the code from `https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus_7.7.0/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/README.md#send-and-receive-a-message`

Comment: Can you try by removing `EntityPath=topic-one` from your connection string? I noticed that your topic name is included in the connection string as well as when you are creating `ServiceBusSender`.

Comment: @GauravMantri: I tried but no luck.

Comment: @StephenCleary  `just noticed that all other samples I saw had a default SharedAccessPolicy called RootManageSharedAccessKey policy available by default in the azure portal. For me, I had to create this policy. To my policy I have given Manage, Send, ReceiveAccess.`

Comment: How long are you waiting for it to return?  If you're experiencing some kind of network issue that results in a timeout, retries kick in and you'd be looking at a total duration of around 3.25 minutes for the failure to surface, assuming default setttings.  I'd suggest trying with the WebSocket transport.  Most often, the root cause for something like this turns out to be that the ports are blocked.  An example can be found here:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample13_AdvancedConfiguration.md#configuring-the-transport

Comment: @JesseSquire: What you said makes sense. But I dont know how to test it ?

Comment: @JesseSquire When I call `await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);` after this line get executed, the program is actually terminating. It not `awating`

Comment: I'd first try setting the transport and running.   If you see the `SendAsync` call complete within ~30 seconds, we can reasonably assume your hang was a timeout.    If that doesn't work, just letting your code run for at least 5 minutes while waiting on `SendAsnyc` would let us prove or rule out the theory that we're timing out while waiting on the connection.

Comment: Ah, if you're terminating and not awaiting, check to be sure that your method signature returns `Task` and the same all the way up your call stack.   It would help to see your entry point code and the entire path to get to the SB use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248125/discussion-between-openstack-and-jesse-squire).

Comment: @JesseSquire: I am not terminating. The program is getting terminated after I call sendMessageAsync(). I have updated the question with entire program.

Answer (score 1):

Needed to change `Sender.Send()`; to `Sender.Send().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: Better solution: `await Sender.Send();`

Comment: For some weird reason await doesn't work for me, project is terminteted instantly when trying to create a message batch. Your answer works for me, but it is frusterating that await doesn't work...